# SizeToContent equivalent for a WinForm?

Tags: .net, winforms, autosize

When playing with WPF, I discovered the [SizeToContent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.sizetocontent.aspx) method, which enables me to create dynamically the content of a window, and then have it automatically resized to fit its content.

I try to do the same thing using WinForms, and it fails.

I used the [AutoSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.autosize.aspx) and [AutoSizeMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.autosizemode.aspx), but it fails to correctly size to its content.

Is there a way to create a WinForm with controls that adjust to the size of their content, as in WPF?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I remember this is a bit tricky in Windows Forms. Basically you need to use auto-sizing containers (e.g. TableLayoutPanel, etc. – and set their `AutoSize` property to `true`) in the form exclusively. Laying out controls with `Anchor` and `Dock` does not work.