# Auto resize winform to show all of a picture

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I've got an image box that I use to preview a screen shot I define with my mouse. What I'd like to do is have my winform change its size in accordance of the size of the picture. As the image size is determined by the size of the rectangle I create using my mouse, it needs to auto adjust.

I already have my image box capable to sizing itself to show the whole picture, how can I make it so my winform shows the whole picture box?

I tried using the following, but it didn't work and I looked at the winform settings but I couldn't see what I needed to do to get the functionality I require:

```
  // "this" is the winform in question
  // imagePreview is the name of my picture box
  this.Width = imagePreview.Width;
  this.Height = imagePreview.Height;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work"? Width and Height properties are really what you need to change.

Comment: Take a look at this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310666/sizetocontent-equivalent-for-a-winform

Comment: That when the image i create is passed back to my form, the picture box changes, but the winform stays the exact same it was before there was an image.

Comment: You are forgetting about the window borders, you'll need to assign the ClientSize property instead.  If the assignment has no effect at all then you probably have a problem with the *this* reference, add this.Show().

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this.Size = new Size(imagePreview.Height, imagePreview.Width);
```

If your form is in a maximized state, you will have to convert back to a "normal" window.

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
this.Size = new Size(imagePreview.Height, imagePreview.Width);
```