# Sizing WinForm Form to show all controls within

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a WinForms application that has a TableLayoutPanel docked inside of a ToolStripContainer docked inside my Form. The TLP has six columns going across it. When the program opens, I'd like to have it check for the size of the content being displayed in the TLP and adjust it's width accordingly so that the users don't have to resize it themselves.

Additionally, it'd be cool if I could restrict the shrinkable size the user can reduce it to to be no less than what it would take to display all content within the Form (basically so it opens to the minimum required width to display all data and can shrink no smaller than that).

I've tried something like `this.Size = new Size(tlpMainView.Width, this.Size.Height)` on Form_Load Event and it doesn't seem to affect anything.

Comment: Have you tried using the autosize properties? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310666/sizetocontent-equivalent-for-a-winform

Comment: `this.MinimumSize`

Comment: Using the autosize doesn't seem to change anything, if I do it on the Form itself or the TLP. I did this.MinimumSize = new Size(blah,blah) and that looks like it'll work I think